# Not able to change the value of the variable

Tags: python, while-loop

```
def paper_doll(text):
    text = list(text)
    l = len(text)
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        letter = text[i]`enter code here`
        print(text[i])
        text.insert(i+1, letter)
        text.insert(i+2, letter)
        i += 1
    return "".join(text)
```

**This Code is Made for the Following question*
**Given a string, return a string where for every character in the original there are three characters**
In the while the value of the letter always remains the first character of the given string
*I would be grateful if somebody says me how to avoid this problem
Thanks at advance*

Comment: Well if you insert 2 letters, your second letter is the one you just duplicated. and the way your code works, it will do that until your initial condition is met. You could either build your new string in a new variable, and affect it after the end of your while loop, or increase `i` by 3 each iteration, and change your while condition to `i<len(text)` instead of a fixed value. On top of everything, you can work with indice on a string as well, you dont need to cast to a list and join at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Fix

The issue is that you update the same variable that you read one

With `"abcd"`

```
i=0 letter=a => insert a, becomes => aabcd
i=1 letter=a => insert a, becomes => aaabcd
...
```

To fix that : use another variable to be updated, and don't use `i` as indice, because it will be wrong after first iteration, and get `aabcddcbabcd`

You need to insert using the new position of the letter in the result

```
def paper_doll(text):
    result = list(text)
    l = len(text)
    i = 0
    while i < l:
        letter = text[i]
        j = result.index(letter)
        result.insert(j + 1, letter)
        result.insert(j + 2, letter)
        i += 1
    return "".join(result)
```

---

#### Improve

So I suggest another logic, an easier one : for each char, append it 3 times to a result

```
def paper_doll(text):
    result = ""
    for letter in text:
        result += letter * 3
    return result
```

Or even

```
def paper_doll(text):
    return "".join(letter * 3 for letter in text)
```